# Login/Logout Trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to create simple login/logout links, but it seems like I can either make the button say login or say logout... I can't get it to switch if the user is logged in or logged out.

First off here's the code from my applications controller:

```
def current_user
  begin
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  rescue Exception => e
    nil
  end
end

def user_signed_in?
  return true if current_user
end
```

So for my login/logout I put this:

```
<% if @current_user %>
<%= link_to("Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %>
```

If I put "@current_user=true" then it will always return "logout" regardless of whether the user is logged in or not.  If I put just "@current_user" then it will always return login regardless.  So what am I supposed to put so that it actually does what I'm trying to do?

**UPDATE** Ok. It's definitely my OmniAuth setup that's causing the problem.  If I login with facebook then the login logout works just fine.  This is probably related to the other issue I posted where active admin was no longer displaying the email address... but if a facebook admin was logged in it would display a facebook username instead. Here's the relevent info:

from app/models/user.rb

```
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
create! do |user|
  user.provider = auth['provider']
  user.uid = auth['uid']
  user.password = user.password_confirmation = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n=6)
  if auth['info']
     user.name = auth['info']['name'] || ""
     user.email = auth['info']['email'] || ""
```

from application_controller.rb

```
def authenticate_active_admin_user!
authenticate_user!
unless current_user.superadmin?
  redirect_to root_url, :alert => "Access denied."
end
end

def current_user
  begin
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  rescue Exception => e
    nil
  end
end

def user_signed_in?
  return true if current_user
end

def correct_user?
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  unless current_user == @user
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => "Access denied."
  end
end

def authenticate_user!
  if !current_user
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => 'You need to sign in for access to this page.'
  end
```

And finally this is what the dubugger returned when logged in with facebook (with a non-facebook user it just returned "--"):

```
!ruby/object:User
attributes:
id: 5
email: courtneyloveless@notevenreal.com
encrypted_password: $10$rMOun/NhxPuMyVEIMeFOGSTw4IVmXGTz/qZ9tS63edevML6
reset_password_token: 
reset_password_sent_at: 
remember_created_at: 
sign_in_count: 0
current_sign_in_at: 
last_sign_in_at: 
current_sign_in_ip: 
last_sign_in_ip: 
created_at: 2013-07-05 05:50:01.280117000 Z
updated_at: 2013-07-08 09:46:32.585278000 Z
superadmin: true
provider: facebook
uid: '6786173'
name: MoneyMark
```

So hopefully that's enough info to get to the bottom of this... It's basically ONLY saying that facebook users are "current_user". (Yet somehow other user logins are working just fine... except I can't do a login logout for them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use Devise gem, but if you wish to create your own authentication logic try following code:

in your application_controller.rb add this:

```
before_filter :login_required!

def login_required!
  unless logged_in?
    redirect_to '/login'
  end
end

def logged_in?
  current_user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

in view add this:

```
<% if @current_user %>
  <%= link_to("Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
```

with Devise you do like this:

```
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to("Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %>
  <% end %>
```

check out the Devise documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: Actually I am using devise. Is there some easy way to do it with devise?

Comment: Sure, devise have helper method `user_signed_in?` you can use this. I'll update my answer

Comment: When I put that it just always says login. I think the other user is right and that the current user is... somehow... set to nil.  I can post the code, but which file should I post? There's the authentications controller, application controller (which I believe I posted above) the users.rb model (from the models, not the other one that is in the admin folder...) See this is how it gets confusing. :)

Comment: It seems like authentication logic working incorrect. Try to debug what value set to session and what value returning current_user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33075/discussion-between-talgat-and-mystic-cola)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the @current_user is nil. Thats why always else part is returned. Create a debugger before if statement and check whether @current_user holds any value or not. It will help you to decide what to do next..

Comment: Ok. Could you explain how to do that? I'm thinking the Oauth login might be screwing with things...

Comment: I did <%= debug user_signed_in? %> and it returned "--- 
..." So I guess that's a nil value then?

Comment: Include gem 'ruby-debug' in your gem file and bundle it. Now in your ruby code wherever you wanna have a break point use keyword debugger. so your program will pause at this point and you can check the values and do other manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

The problem was that the application_controller was overwriting devise's own "def current_user"

First I just deleted the "def current_user" entry... and regular logins worked fine... but the facebook logins didn't work. So I simply renamed all "def current_user" entries in the application controller to "current_user2"... like so:

```
def current_user2
begin
@current_user2 ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
rescue Exception => e
nil
end
end
```

And now everything works the way it should with user_signed_in? :)